# Required fields in form not validated

Tags: ajax, forms

I am currently constructing a form using an Ajax handler. The problem is that since i used Ajax, the submitting part is run without returning any error message. It is only when I clear the cache that all the errors appear (and the form disappear).

```
function My_Modile_form($form, $form_state, $arg){
     //constructing the form with REQUIREDfields
  $form ['submit'] = array (
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#ajax' => array (
          'callback' => 'mymodule_form_ajax_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'result-div' 
      ),
      '#value' => t ( 'Lancer la simulation' ),
      '#weight' => 10000 
  );
}

function My_Module_form_validate($form_id, $form) {

  $form_numbers = array (
      'field_one',
      'field_two' 
  );
  foreach ( $form_numbers as $form_number ) {
    $numb = $form ['input'] [$form_number];
    if (! is_numeric ( $numb )) {
      form_set_error ( $form ['complete form'] [$form_number] ['#title'], 'ERROR !' );
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_form_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $form ['simul_message_retour'] += mymodule_form_submit ( $form, $form_state );
  return $form ['simul_message_retour'];
}

function mymodule_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    // Submitting part
}
```

Has anyone met this issue before with Ajax forms ?

Thank you,

EDIT: I just found that  the hook_form_submit is called BEFORE the hook_form_validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the framework for Form-handling:

```
function customregister_custom_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form['first_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Vorname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => '0',
    '#required' => TRUE
  );
  $form['last_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE
  );
  $form ['submit'] = array (
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#ajax' => array (
    'callback' => 'customregister_custom_form_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'customregister-custom-form'
    ),
    '#value' => t ( 'Lancer la simulation' ),
    '#weight' => 10000
  );
  return $form;
}

function customregister_custom_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  if (! is_numeric ( $form_state['values']['first_name'] )) {
    form_set_error ( 'first_name', 'ERROR !' );
  }
  if (! is_numeric ( $form_state['values']['last_name'] )) {
    form_set_error ( 'last_name', 'ERROR !' );
  }
}

function customregister_custom_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('custom_form_callback');
  //customregister_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state);
  $formular = drupal_get_form('customregister_custom_form');
  $formular = render($formular);
  return $formular;
}

function customregister_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('custom_form_submit');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I did. The function is called but the error message is not shown when Javascript is activated in the browser. I change the post accordingly

Comment: I dont't see any form-values in your implementation. Usually all form-values are stored per reference in `$form_state['values']`

Comment: Oh yes i see now. I tried it too. It is still the same. I think it has something to do with the fact that i've put the form inside a block. It might be caching the block. need to investigate more this way

Comment: check my last edit about setting the error

Comment: Did change the parameters in the form_set_error(). Not solved.

Comment: `form_set_error('HTML_ATTRIBUTE_NAME', 'Error message');`

Comment: Actually, It happens also with the others fields that are marked as required  without any operation in the `hook_form_validate()`

Comment: I found a solution to the issue. I've called back the validating function in the hook_form_submit (I know, not very pretty, but does the job).
Thanks a lot for your help Benone_

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my_module_form_wrapper" class="wrapper-for-form">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  $form['other_elements'] = array(
      //code...
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#weight' => 5,
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#validate' => array('my_module_form_validate'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_module_form_submit',
      'wrapper' => 'my_module_form_wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
}

function my_module_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  //Your validation logic
  $form_numbers = array(
    'field_one',
    'field_two'
  );
  foreach ($form_numbers as $form_number) {
    $numb = $form ['input'] [$form_number];
    if (!is_numeric($numb)) {
      form_set_error($form ['complete form'] [$form_number] ['#title'], 'ERROR !');
    }
  }
}

function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_validate_form('my_module_form', $form, $form_state);
  if (form_get_errors()) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    $form['your_elements']['#value'] = $form_state['input']['elements'];
    return $form;
  }
  else {
    // continue with your submit logic.
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the drupal_validate_form() function you proposed. 
As i manage the form with a bloc, the `return $form;` returned the form (again) showing two times the form. It would have been perfect to have something like `refresh($form)`. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Check your elements on page. and check whether the wrapper is in the place. that is where the form is get replaced after process. This line in the code: 'wrapper' => 'my_module_form_wrapper',

Comment: I've added updated code. Check prefix and suffix to form. This will replace your form on response.