# AJAX event returns same data always

Tags: forms, hooks, ajax, webforms

So, this is a simple form, and what the ajax call back does here is that it returns the value of a field that's being changed.

The problem is that, only the value of the first change is returned. If i change the value a second time, the returned value is the same as first. 
I'm not sure what is happening here, it needs a better pair of eyes.

Here's the code

```
<?php

    //Create raffle form
    function raffle_create_form($form, &$form_state)
    {
        dpm($form_state);
        //Basic raffle info
        $form['raf_raffle_name'] = array(
            '#type' => "textfield",
            "#prefix" => "<h5>Raffle information</h5><hr>",
            "#title" => "Raffle Name:",
            "#required" => TRUE
        );

        $form['raf_allowed_number'] = array(
            '#type' => "textfield",
            "#title" => "Number of allowed members",
            "#required" => TRUE,
            '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_number')
        );

        $form['raf_start_now'] = array(
            "#type" => "checkbox",
            "#title" => "Start raffle now?"
        );

        $form['raf_end_date'] = array(
            "#type" => "date",
            "#title" => "When to close this raffle?",
            "#required" => TRUE
        );

        $form['raf_prize_type'] = array(
            '#type' => "select",
            "#options" => array('gift' => 'Steam Gift', 'hardware' => 'Gaming peripherals'),
            "#title" => "Prize type",
            "#required" => TRUE,
            "#ajax" => array(
                'callback' => 'raffle_create_form_type_steam',
                'wrapper' => 'steam_options',
                'event' => 'change',
                'method' => 'replace',
            ),
        );

        $form['raf_prize_name'] = array(
            '#type' => "textfield",
            "#title" => "Prize name",
            "#prefix" => "<div id='steam_options'></div>",
            "#required" => TRUE
        );

        $form['raf_prize_about'] = array(
            '#type' => "textarea",
            "#resizeable" => true,
            "#title" => "Prize description"
        );

        $form['raf_prize_thumb'] = array(
            '#type' => "file",
            "#title" => "Prize thumbnail"
        );

        $form['raf_prize_link'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => "Link to product"
        );

        $form['raf_raffle_create'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => "Create Raffle",
        );

        $form['#submit'][] = 'raffle_create_form_submit';

        return $form;
    }

    function raffle_create_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
    {
        dpm($form_state);
    }

    function raffle_create_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
    {

    }

    function raffle_create_form_type_steam($form, &$form_state)
    {
        return $form_state['values']['raf_prize_type'];
    }**
```

Comment: It could help [form framework](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/179495/51506)

Comment: sorry, that's not what im lookin for

Comment: why are you not using #suffix key?

Comment: @ShabirA. Because, i need to add a new input field and not replace an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever data is returned must be encapsulated in a div element of the same id as the wrapper.

This fixed the problem for me :)

```
function raffle_create_form_type_steam($form, &$form_state)
{
    if($form_state['values']['raf_prize_type'] == 'hardware')
    {
        return "<div id='steam_options'></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        return  $form['raf_steam_option_game_append'] = array(
                '#type' => 'checkbox',
                '#title' => 'Check if Steamer has game in library',
                '#description' => 'Does not allow gamer to join raffle if said gift already exists within gamer\'s steam library',
                "#prefix" => "<div id='steam_options'>",
                "#suffix" => "</div>"
            );
    }

}
```